# find a span id with watir

Tags: watir

On the website, there's a field that's populated by a user by clicking a Browse button then selecting a file. I can't figure out how get watir to populate it. We ran test cases a couple years ago that found it by `browser.fileField(:id,"file01").set(x)` but that no longer works.

```
irb(main):154:0>  bowser.fileField(:id,"file01").exists?
NoMethodError: undefined method `fileField' for #<Watir::IE:0x35de4d8>
        from (irb):154
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

I can kind of find it, but haven't been able to get farther than this:

```
irb(main):159:0> browser.form(:id, '104').span(:id, "file_1").exists?
=> true
```

here is the code:

```
<form id="104" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="post" >
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="create">
<input id="external" type="hidden" value="0" name="external">
<table class="text fullWidth" cellspacing="0" summary="Sending Form">
<tbody>
<tr>
<script type="text/javascript">
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td class="fRequired">
<td class="fText">
<table class="fInput">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<span id="file_01">
<input id="file01" class="fFile" type="file" onchange="writename(this.value, shortfile1'); return true;" tabindex="2" name="file01">
<span id="shortfile1"> aby.JPG</span>
</span>
<br>
<span id="file_02">
<br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
browser.file_field(:id => "file01").set(x)
```

For future reference, API for watir-classic gem is here: http://rdoc.info/gems/watir-classic

Comment: irb(main):087:0>  browser.file_field(:id => "file01").exists?
=> true

thanks! I'm not very talented with automation. Kind of an eternal newbie, I guess. That finds it.

Comment: The upload field now gets populated with the designated file. However, I get a timeout that I can't figure out.       irb(main):015:0> browser.file_field(:id => "file01").set("C:\\image.jpg")
Watir::Wait::TimeoutError: timed out after 5 seconds
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.4.0/lib/watir-classic/wait.rb:29:in `until'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.4.0/lib/watir-classic/dialogs/file_field.rb:18:in `set'
        from (irb):15
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):016:0>